# How do I change the language of date and time on boot?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, language-support

I recently installed **Kubuntu 19.2** on my PC. I have a problem tho. When I was choosing the time zone in the installation, I picked the city I live in. However, it automatically set my date and time language to the language spoken in that country and not english, the language I want to use. I did set the date and time language to english in settings and it seemed to work fine. Except at boot. When I boot up my computer, on the login screen that language is still displayed. How do I change this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify your OS/release?  There was no 2019-February (19.2) release of Kubuntu (or any other Ubuntu flavor), and 19.2 is used by non-Ubuntu distros (which don't use the *yy.mm* format Ubuntu does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, the installer 'guesses' the formats setting, including date and time, based on the location you pick. You can change it by opening `/etc/default/locale` for editing and change the values there to your liking.